# R sorting string vector based on a specific character without removing the last item in the vector

Tags: r

I have a vector containing these items

```
[1] "3 * x1" "-0.2 * x3" "-0.1 * x2" "-7.85"
```

Is it possible to sort it based on the value beside x without removing the last item in such a way that it will look like this

```
[1] "3 * x1" "-0.1 * x2" "-0.2 * x3""-7.85"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```r
vec <- c("3 * x1", "-0.2 * x3", "-0.1 * x2", "-7.85")


xsort <- function(vec){
  l <- grepl("x\\d*", vec)
  s <- as.numeric(gsub(".*x(\\d*).*", "\\1", vec))
  s <- ifelse(l, s, Inf)
  vec[order(s)]
}
xsort(vec)
#> [1] "3 * x1"    "-0.1 * x2" "-0.2 * x3" "-7.85"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```r
vec2 <- gsub(".*\\bx([-+]?[0-9][.0-9]*)\\b.*", "\\1", vec)
vec2[vec2 == vec] <- ""
vec[order(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(vec2)))]
# [1] "3 * x1"    "-0.1 * x2" "-0.2 * x3" "-7.85"
```

Regex:

```
".*\\bx([-+]?[0-9]\\.?[0-9]*)\\b.*"
 .*                             .*   anything, discard leading/following text
   \\b                       \\b     word-boundary
       (                    )        capture group, "remember" within this --> \\1 later
        [-+]?                        '-' or '+', optional
             [0-9]                   at least one digit ...
                  \\.?[0-9]*         ... followed by an optional dot and
                                        zero or more digits
```

Because this makes no change in the case of `"-7.85"`, we need to follow-up by checking for "no change", as in `vec2 == vec`.

Answer (score 1):

```
v <- c("3 * x1", "-0.2 * x3", "-0.1 * x2", "-7.85")
v[c(order(as.integer(sub(".*x", "", v[-length(v)]))), length(v))]
#> [1] "3 * x1"    "-0.1 * x2" "-0.2 * x3" "-7.85"
```

Comment: It seems odd to be hard-coding the order of `"-7.85"`.

Comment: I took the OP's statement "without removing the last item" to mean that the last element in the original vector should remain the last item in the reordered vector because the last element is assumed to not have an `x` term. This lines up with the OP's example outpout.

Comment: Ok, that's a different interpretation; I thought it might mean to do the sorting without having to remove the last element before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
as.vector(names(sort(sapply(v, function(x) gsub('.*x','',x)))))
[1] "-7.85"     "3 * x1"    "-0.1 * x2" "-0.2 * x3"
```